# Angular version upgrade 8 to 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, node-sass, angular-upgrade

I am updating my angular project version from 8 to 9, after resolving other build errors when i run ng serve my compilation is getting stuck at

`15% building 43/44 modules 1 active ...v9\ABCD\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-3!C:\Project\ABCD-v9\ABCD\src\app\styles\styles.scss`

Comment: Did you follow the guide at https://update.angular.io/ ?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes i followed the steps from here only

Comment: Have you tried to remove the node_modules folder and run 'npm i'?

Comment: Yup already tried @n_denny

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with the styles.scss file, can you post that file in here too?

Comment: It was resolved by npm unistall node-sass

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved, i removed node-sass by unistalling